# How can I mount a folder from an ubuntu virtual machine on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, sshfs

I tried `sshfs`, but the local directory where I want to mount a folder from the VM does not open after running the command.

Comment: I am using virtualbox and the performance is quite good. I am running hortonworks hadoop vm. I have used sshfs before for mounting from servers, just that the same is somehow not working for VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the `Guest Additions` on the virtual machine. These can be dowloaded from within the virtual machine from the *Devices > Install Guest Additions* menu.
2. Add the folder you wish to share to the *Shared Folders*, this option can also be found in the *Devices* menu.
3. The folder can now be mounted with

   `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) folder ~/host`

For more info, or troubleshooting, check out [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders) Ubuntu Help article.

Answer (score -1):

OS: Ubuntu
Install the `VBoxGuestAdditions`. You don't have to reboot the system.
See https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ for newest available version...

```
$ wget https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.10/VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.10.iso -P /tmp
$ sudo mount -o loop /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.10.iso /mnt
$ sudo apt-get install bzip2 tar
$ sudo sh /mnt/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

After that you can use the GUI for mounting folders. You must close the modal window with the listed folders, to actualy add your newly added folder.
The folder doesn't have to exist on the guest, it will be create.

You also have to add your user to the group 'vboxsf' in the guest os, to get access rights for the shared folders:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $USER
$ newgrp vboxsf
```